# SQL check if row exists in cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am doing a select that returns a table of roleIds.
I was looking for a method of iterating through the values and run a delete or (stored proc) for each row value. After trying many different suggestions this is what I have:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @RoleId bigint

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT cr.RoleId
FROM ClientRole AS cr
INNER JOIN userRole AS ur ON cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
AND cr.ClientId = 564564564

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @RoleId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        --NEED TO CHECK IF RolePermissions ACTUALLY HAS THE PERMISSION
        DELETE  
        FROM RolePermissions
        WHERE RoleId = @RoleId
        AND PermissionId = 12341234

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @RoleId
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur

ROLLBACK
```

Currently when trying to "delete" is gives an error because the row it is trying to delete doesn't exists for some RoleIds. I tried If, WHILE, CASE but not sure what I should be doing here as I don't know how to pass over the RoleId if it doesnt have the row. It seems cursors arent recommended but could not make the same work by putting it in a temp table.

Appreciate any suggestions

EDIT::

Initially I was trying to run a stored proc from the cursor:
Originally I was trying to run a  stored proc on each roleId:

```
    begin tran
    exec dbo.usp_DeleteRolePermission @RoleId = @RoleId,
    @PermissionId =  12341234,
    @PublishToCache = 1
commit
```

Comment: Can you add your table schema and relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not need a cursor for this. A single statement like this can easily be transformed into a procedure:

```
declare @ClientId     int = 564564564;
declare @PermissionId int = 12341234;

delete rp
from RolePermissions rp
where PermissionId = @PermissionId
  and exists (
    select 1
    from ClientRole as cr
      inner join userRole as ur 
        on cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
      and cr.ClientId = @ClientId
      where ur.RoleId = rp.RoleId
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your example why you actually need to iterate over the cursor and delete each and every record individually. Can't you just issue a single `DELETE` ? Something to the tune of

```
DELETE  
FROM RolePermissions
WHERE RoleId IN (SELECT cr.RoleId
                 FROM ClientRole AS cr
                 INNER JOIN userRole AS ur ON cr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
                 AND cr.ClientId = 564564564)
AND PermissionId = 12341234
```

Comment: It's still unclear why you need to loop over a cursor for something that can be expressed in a single statement.

Comment: how do I run a stored proc for every value in a column in a table returned in a select statement ? I only reverted to using a normal "delete" to make it easier than using the stored proc (my first choice)

Comment: Maybe you wan't to update to your question to make it clear to other readers that your intention is to use some opaque proc and not `DELETE`` the rows.